# How to find / replace text in CSV and pull it into an HTML table with PHP?

Tags: php, csv, replace, import

Thanks to some help I got here, I managed to pull specific rows and columns of data from a CSV into an HTML table using PHP.

The working table is here: http://digitaldemo.net/table/table.php

Here is the data in the CSV (screenshot)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5pa0ruxxnydwhr4/Screenshot%202014-11-17%2012.19.26.png?dl=0

and my code:

```
<?php 
echo "<table cellspacing=\"5\" cellpadding=\"5\">";
echo "<thead><tr align=\"center\">";
echo "<td>Cumulative<br />Total Returns (%) as of [10]</td>";
echo "<td>Quarter</td>";
echo "<td>YTD</td>";
echo "<td>1YR</td>";
echo "<td>3YR</td>";
echo "<td>5YR</td>";
echo "<td>10YR</td>";
echo "<td>Since<br>Inception<sup>1</sup></td>";
echo "</tr></thead>";
$filter = array(
  '2' => '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8',
  '3' => '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8',
  '5' => '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9'
);

if (($handle = fopen("source.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {

        $row = 1;

        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

          if(array_key_exists($row, $filter))
          {
            $columns = explode(",", $filter[$row]);   

            echo "<tr align=\"center\">";                                                 

            for($i = 0; $i <= count($data); $i++)
            { 
              if(in_array($i, $columns))
              {
                echo "<td>" . $data[$i - 1] . "</td>";
              }
            }

            echo "</tr>";
          }
            $row++;
        }
    }

echo "</table>";    

?>
```

My question now is how do I find / replace text in the CSV so that it shows up the way that I want in the table (e.g. changing Row_1 in the table above to Apple)?

Also, how can I auto format any numbers (including those w/ leading zeros) to two decimal places?

Thanks in advance!

Cynthia

Comment: what `Row_1`? There's no "Row_1" anywhere in your code. If you want to translate the numbers to something else, YOU will have to provide the translation rules. As for number formatting, RTFM: http://php.net/number_format and http://php.net/sprintf

Comment: Row_1 isn't a variable. It's the text in the first column of row 2 in the CSV

Comment: How will you determine which values should be replaced, and what their replacements should be? I think it might be better not to try to find and replace in the CSV, but instead to just look for the values you want to replace as you are looping through the CSV data and output the replacement value instead.